# Only draw objects within arbitrary bounding box in TikZ?

Tags: tikz-pgf

Is it possible to define a bounding box for a TikZ picture outside of which nothing is drawn, even though there might be things defined there?

In my special case I want to draw all points `P` that can be written as `P = a*B_1 + b*B_2` for two base vectors `B_1`, `B_2` and integers `a`, `b` that are located within some specified box (e.g. `(-10, -10) rectangle (10, 10)`).

Comment: `\clip (-10,-10) rectangle (10,10);` at the top

Comment: Thanks! Would there also be a possibility to do this only within a certain scope of the picture (e.g. only hide certain circles outside of the rectangle and keep the other objects visible)?

Comment: Yes inside a `scope` environment the clip is only valid inside that scope

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To exclude certain portion of a drawing the command/option `clip`can be used. Let us draw random black dots inside a 4cm x 4cm box:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[point/.style={fill,inner sep=0pt, minimum size=2pt, circle}]
    \node[draw,minimum size=4cm+2pt,inner sep=0pt](bounding box) at (2,2) {};
    \foreach \i in {1,...,100}{\node[point] (p\i) at ({4*rnd},{4*rnd}) {};};
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

If we now use the `\clip` command, everything after the command will be clipped off the drawing. Unless the `\clip`ping is done inside a **`scope`**, then only what's inside the scope will be clipped. To show these effects let us continue with our drawing, adding red dots on top of the previously defined black dots and a square in the middle (note that the red dots are inside a scope and the square outside).

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=2mm]{standalone}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[point/.style={fill,inner sep=0pt, minimum size=2pt, circle}]
    %\clip (2,0) rectangle (4,4); %Clips everything including the graph bounding box
    \node[draw,minimum size=4cm+2pt,inner sep=0pt](bounding box) at (2,2) {};
    %\clip (bounding box.north) rectangle (bounding box.south east); %Clips everything after it
    \foreach \i in {1,...,100}{\node[point] (p\i) at ({4*rnd},{4*rnd}) {};};
    \begin{scope}
      %\clip (bounding box.north) rectangle (bounding box.south east); %Clips only the scope
      \foreach \i in {1,...,100} \node[point,red] at (p\i) {};
    \end{scope}
    \node[draw,fill=white] at (bounding box.center){};
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The first `\clip`, clips everything including the bounding box, leaving half of the drawing size (2cm x 2cm):

[image: Clip as first thing]

The second `\clip`, clips everything *but* the `bounding box` node that was defined before it, leaving the graph size 4cm x 4cm but with only half of it filled with stuff:

[image: Clip in the middle of the drawing]

Finally, the third `\clip` clips only the **`scope`** (red dots), leaving the square intact (even though it was defined after the `\clip`) and half of the black dots which were hidden underneath the red ones:

[image: Clip inside a scope]

What all this means is that if you want to clip the whole drawing `\clip` should be the first thing issued in you drawing. If you want to clip everything after a certain point just `\clip` after it. And if you want to clip only some stuff right in the middle of the drawing, put this stuff inside a **`scope`**.